# I want to send coordinate value from C# code to shader code in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader, vertex-shader

I want to send coordinate value from **C#** code to **shader** code in Unity.

### C# code:

```
public class SendWorldPositionToShaderProgram : MonoBehaviour {

    void Start () {
        Renderer renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        renderer.material.SetVector("_WorldPosition", transform.position);
        }
    }
}
```

### Shader code:

```
Shader "Custom/MyRotateShader2" {

    Properties {
        _WorldPosition("WorldPosition", Vector) = (0, 0, 0, 0)
    }
    SubShader {
        Tags
        {
            "RenderType" = "Opaque"
        }

        CGPROGRAM

        #pragma surface surf Lambert vertex:vertex_program
        #include "UnityCG.cginc"

        float4 _WorldPosition;

        void vertex_program(inout appdata_full v) 
        {
            float4 wp = _WorldPosition;
            wp.x; // is not real coordinate!
            wp.y; // not too!
            wp.z; // not too!
        }

        void surf( Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) 
        {

            ...

        }

        ENDCG
    }
    FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```

Comment: Can you explaine what problem are you have?

Comment: Removing the public property should help. Just leave the definition after the include, its enough.

Comment: Compiler said: undeclared identifier '_WorldPosition' (>_<)

Comment: Sorry, when I click RUN button, everything go well.